# Getting newest message in GROUP_BY

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to group a bunch of `Message`s by the `User`s who sent them. My current solution gives me the oldest `Message` in the groups.

```
$user->messages()->groupBy('user_from')->get();
```

How can I achieve the reversed messages?

Comment: laravel should have a orderBy function, too. So you could just $user->messages()->groupBy('user_from')->orderBy('date', 'ASC')->get();

Comment: That just orders the groups. Within each group, I need to get the latest message, not the oldest

Comment: Maybe you can order first. Group afterwards.

Comment: That makes no difference. :-)

Comment: That's MySQL thing. You can't order groupped query (before the group by). What's the relation between `User` and `Message`?

Answer (score 0):

@Maeh,

If you are using timestamps() while migration then
you could do orderBy('FIELD_NAME', 'DESC')

Comment: That just orders the groups. Within each group, I need to get the latest message, not the oldest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Table has an ID, you can order by the primary key ID ascending to get the messages that are near the top.

Comment: That just orders the groups. Within each group, I need to get the latest message, not the oldest

Answer (score 0):

Try `orderBy('columnName', 'desc ');` after your `groupBy('user_form')`

where columnName should be that column which have time

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too hard.

```
$user->messages()->orderBy('created_date', 'DESC')->first();
```

No need to group because you are already grabbing messages by the user.

Comment: Yeah that's the point, each user model in your collection will contain the newest message.  Then you loop through the users and echo the message or whatever you plan on doing with them.  Otherwise you have all users' newest message attached to a single user model.  That's bad practice.

Comment: @user3158900 I think you got it wrong. OP is trying to get first message per sender, not first of all his messages.